# Covering dimension of $[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

Equip $[0,1]$ with its usual metric topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}.$ It is well known that the covering dimension of $[0,1]$ is $1$.

**Question**: Given a fixed number $n$, can I construct a finite open cover $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ of $[0,1]$ such that any finite open refinement of multiplicity $2$  needs to consist of at least $k$ elements for an arbitrary number $k$?

For example, can I construct an open cover of $[0,1]$ consisting of $3$ elements such that any open refinement of multiplicity $2$ needs to have at least $7$ elements?

In general, given a compact space $X$ of covering dimension $s$ and a fixed number $n$, can I construct a finite open cover $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ of $X$ such that any finite open refinement of multiplicity $s+1$  needs to consist of at least $k$ elements for an arbitrary number $k$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Definitions:

**Covering dimension**: A nonempty topological space $X$ is said to have the covering dimension $n$ if $n$ is the smallest non-negative integer with the property such that each finite open cover of $X$ has a finite open refinement of multiplicity at most $n+1$.

**Multiplicity of a cover** A cover of a topological space $X$ has multiplicity $n$ if and only if it is the smallest non-negative integer such that each point $x$ of $X$ belongs to at most $n$ elements of the cover.

Comment: Your definition of covering dimension is correct only for compact spaces. For general $X$ you have to require that each open cover of $X$ has an open refinement of multiplicity at most $n+1$.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Probably you mean that you are given $n$ **and** $k$. But this is not what you have written.

Comment: @PaulFrost Engelking defines covering dimension in terms on finite coverings. This could be helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228574/two-definitions-of-lebesgue-covering-dimension

Comment: @PaulFrost Regarding your second question, I want to fix $n$ (the amount of sets in the original cover) and then for each $k$ construct a covering with $n$ elements whose appropriate refinement has to have at least $k$ elements.

Comment: 1. I was not aware of Engelking's definition, and your link shows that it agrees with that I had in mind except in "exotic" cases. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: 2. So you want to know whether for each $n$ and each $k$ you can construct an open cover $\mathcal U (n,k)$ having a suitable property. Your questions reads (at least for me) as if you want to know whether for each $n$ you can construct an open cover $\mathcal U (n)$ having a suitable property. But it is obvious that $\mathcal U (n)$ must also depend on $k$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, you are right about what I meant. I am sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{V} = \{V_j : j \in J\}$ is a multiplicity $m$ open refinement of $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n.$

For $1 \leq i \leq n,$ define $A_i = \{V \in \mathcal{V} : V \subseteq U_i\}$ and note that $$W_i = \bigcup \left(A_i\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{i-1}A_k\right)\right), \qquad 1\leq i \leq n$$ defines an open refinement of $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n$ with at most $n$ elements and at most multiplicity $m.$

---

*Notation:* The [arbitrary union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions) of a set of sets $\mathcal{A}$ is defined by $$\displaystyle\bigcup \mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A = \{x : \exists A \in \mathcal{A}, x \in A \in \mathcal{A}\}$$

Comment: @PaulFrost Without naming my initial refinement, that was the best I could do.  I have named it now.  Is it more clear?  As for your question in your edit, the sets $A_i \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^{i-1} A_k$ are sets of open sets, hence their union is open.